# Different Http 404 - Returning from Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, web-config

I have a MVC ASP.NET website in which I have the following on the `web.config`

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/redir/Home/Http404" />
</customErrors>
```

So when I try to navigate to an address that does not exist I get my `Http404` view located under `Home` which is correct.

Now I have a special situation in which I want to manually return the same Http 404 and I am seeing the IIS 8 error instead of my Http404 view.

**Controller :**

```
return new HttpNotFoundResult();
```

How to avoid this IIS8 error page, and still make my view the error provider?

**EDIT***

I found out that if instead of `HttpNotFoundResult()` I use the old `throw new HttpException(404, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");` it works.

Why this difference ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you register a global `HandleError` filter?

Comment: Yes I have the ``filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<customErrors>` section is aimed to control the behavior when an **Application Error** occurs. That's also why it's defined under the `<system.web>` section.

When you explicitly throw an `HttpException` (or when any other internal exception occurs) the `<customErrors>` settings will be used as it's considered (rightfully) an application error.

On the other hand, when you simply `return HttpNotFoundResult()`, no application error is being thrown (internally, it just sets the HTTP response status code and message to 404) and the `MvcHandler` will hand over the request to the next handler in the pipeline. So you eventually end up with a regular **Server Error** that is handled by IIS just like any other '404 not found' request, and the `<customErrors>` section does not affect its behavior.

So, you need to control IIS behavior when regular server error occurs. To do this, use the `<system.webServer/httpErrors>` section as follows:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
    <remove statusCode="404"/>
    <error statusCode="404" path="/redir/Home/Http404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

See [Documentation](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors)